# How to get color output from SSH command

Tags: ssh, color

I'm trying to run some commands remotely and recieve the output back with color. What am I missing?

Here's what I've got so far:

**example.sh**

```
. /etc/profile
[[ -f ~/.profile ]] && . ~/.profile;
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc;
echo "hello remote"
cd /vagrant/repositories/repo
pwd
phpunit --color
```

I'm piping the script into ssh as follows:

`cat example.sh | ssh vagrant@localhost /bin/bash -s`

Comment: the linux tools usually recognize that on the other side of pipe is not a terminal. I don't think there is some universal way to force all of them to do so.

Comment: @Jakuje — Is the same true for `ssh -T`?

Comment: `-T` removes the TTY allocation. Probably you can trick it with `ssh -tt`, but I haven't try it yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using `-tt` switches, which will force TTY allocation and it will trick the remote program to write also the colors. Minimal test I can run on my system:

Without colors:

```
ssh localhost "cowsay hello | lolcat"
```

With colors:

```
ssh -tt localhost "cowsay hello | lolcat"
```

Comment: This does output color, but the ssh session does not automatically exit like in the normal "single command" mode.

Comment: it does for me. What server/client version of openssh are you using?

Comment: `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`

Comment: I have 6.7p1. It should work the same if you don't have any special shell on remote side. Adding `exit` at the end of command can do some change, but not sure ...

Comment: I added an `exit` to my script and that solved that part.